# css box shadow + transparent background images = intuitive breakdown

Tags: transparency, background-image, css

- I have a button image I'm using as a background image for some links.
- The background image has rounded corners.
- I want to use a css drop shadow instead of putting the drop shadow in the image

The problem is, the drop shadow appears to be drawn *around* the element.  Although I kind of expected to see the drop shadow color through the transparent parts of the background image, I'm seeing the background color instead ([see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doub1ejack/cXKTx/)).

My actual goal is a little more complex, but if I can satify my first three bullet points then I can nail this task.  Specifically, what I want to do is use two nested elements with background images of the right and left parts of a button image (rounded corners) so that I can use the same css to wrap a 'button' around text of any length.  Since the backgrounds overlap in a css 'sliding doors' style, a png alpha drop shadow shows a 2x dark section where the images overlap.  Soo.. I thought I'd use a css shadow, but as you can see in the jsFiddle, there are problems with that too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Box-shadows don't show through transparent backgrounds. A more simple test case would be:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}​
```

The output expected would be a nice blurred black square right? Well... no, it's a white square with a dropshadow. http://jsfiddle.net/UjhrW/

To achieve what you want to do you will need separate markup for the dropshadow, fill it with white, and then set the spill of the shadow so it looks like a blurry square...

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 6px #000;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Etmty/

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 6px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, that creates the impression of a nice drop shadow.  Are you recommending that I then position the background images I want over the .box div?  Seems like it should work..

Comment: Actually, that's pretty good: http://jsfiddle.net/doub1ejack/AAAMH/.  I have already addressed this issue by very carefully sizing my div with the box shadow to be the same size & shape as the background image, but that feels a little fragile.  I like this much better, thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a separate div? Just add the shadow to the containing div. - http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/AAAMH/2/ unless I'm missing something, you've got more code than is needed.

Comment: According to the original jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/doub1ejack/cXKTx/ the div should be slightly larger than the background image.

Comment: @scott: the problem with adding shadow to the containing div is that the css shadow does not show through any transparent parts of the background image. So if you have an image with a transparent hole in the middle you see the parent background color - not the drop shadow color.  It hurts the brain..