# Unable to convert button design in Figma to CSS code

Tags: html, css, sass, 3d, figma

I designed this button in Figma but when I copy the CSS properties from the inspect section from Figma I won't get the same output, what I'm doing wrong here?

Figma file: `https://www.figma.com/file/r3z3qwUsYGsn9SVDefWVoM/problem?node-id=2%3A6`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: left;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;
  border: none;
  line-height: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.666667px;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(135.37deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 4.29%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) 95.6%);
  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), -5px -5px 10px #FAFBFF, 5px 5px 10px rgba(190, 106, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Wednesday</button>
</div>
```

I want the button to be like that

[image]

and this is what i'm getting right now

[image]

Comment: don't post codepen link! paste your code here in a snippet! that will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, button shadows won't show through the button's body, even if the body is transparent. You will have to find another way to render a very rich button like that.

See my proof of concept below.

You can also find a detailed explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573440/46915

```css
body {
  background: #777;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: left;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 64px;

  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none !important;

  /*background: linear-gradient(135.37deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 4.29%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) 95.6%);*/

  background-blend-mode: soft-light;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), -5px -5px 10px #FAFBFF, 5px 5px 10px rgba(190, 106, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Wednesday</button>
</div>
```